# string to java.io.file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to open a file from the device. I get this error

FilePath is a string which contains the path of the file. Is there any way to convert string to java.io.file in C#.

```
 var FilePath= Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/newfolder" + "/example.pdf";
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(filePath));
 intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(f), "application/msword");
 StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You get *which* error?

Comment: cannot convert from  'string' to 'Java.IO.file' ---- this is the error

Comment: you could convert the path to file and pass it as parameter I think .`File file = new File(FilePath);`

Comment: @kaj I tried using File file = new File(FilePath); but File is a static class. because of that I cant make a instance of the class 'File'.

Comment: Sorry didn't familiar with  java nor xamarin but you could write it as : `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(FilePath));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can download report using WebClient (Same as android). Display a custom notification to the user after downloading. And when user click on notification open the report in device default apps (ex: .pdf => pdf reader). use `Java.IO.File` to get saved report uri.

```
        var ReportAbsolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Folder";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ReportAbsolutePath);

        try
        {
            string reportSavedPath = ReportAbsolutePath + "/ReportName.pdf";
            var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(reportSavedPath));

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);

                var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                var notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.app_icon, "Title");
                notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;
                notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "title", "desc", 
                PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0));
                notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);


                ShowToastMessage("Report downloaded successfully.");
            };
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(reportUrl), reportSavedPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowToastMessage("Error occurred while downloading the report");
        }
```

Comment: "var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(reportSavedPath));"It works for me. thanks XD

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to convert string to java.io.file in C#.

You can use the [`File`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.IO.File/) class.

For example:

```
        var FilePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/newfolder" + "/example.pdf";
        File file = new File(FilePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file));
```

Comment: I have tried that , File file = new File(FilePath);  I cannot create an instance of the static class 'File'

Comment: @TharinduWanninayake You should use Java.IO.File, not System.IO.File.